# Need to get name of cloudformation template used to deploy ec2 from the command line using aws cli or api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, aws-cloudformation

I used a cloudformation template to create an ec2 instance. Is there any way besides tagging that I can get the name of the cloudformation template via the command line?

Comment: found this solution, not thoroughly tested - but works in most cases: command line command: GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data/ | grep 'cfn-init -s' | awk '{print $3}'

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1: Tagging**

Tagging is going to be the cleanest and easiest way to get that data. You do need to do some advance work and this won't work for existing instances, but it's going to be fast and reliable.

**Method 2: Cross-referencing**

If you have the instance id, you can ask Cloudformation to search for it's sibling stack resources, from which you can infer the stack name, id, etc.

```
c = boto.cloudformation.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
c.describe_stack_resources(physical_resource_id='i-830e2869')[0].stack_name
```

If the instance is not part of a stack, you'll get a `Stack for i-830e2869 does not exist` 400 error.

**Method 3: User data**

I'll admit - this was pretty creative so kudos for thinking it up.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data | grep 'cfn-init -s' | awk '{print $3}'
```

The reason this works is that instances created by Cloudformation need to run `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init` to install packages and `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal` in order to report their successful creation and one of the parameters is the stack name.

It'll fail if someone edits the user-data, but despite feeling a bit hacky, it seems pretty reliable. I still wouldn't recommend using it in prod given it's brittle reliance on a script parameter.